# build file name for image used as resource C#

Tags: c#, winforms

trying to build the file name for image i have in resource folder and it show it ass error.
i create the file name into string parameter,
already create btn as button' look for "**fileName**" parameter.
**the error is**: Error 1   'warCards.Properties.Resources' does not contain a definition for '**fileName**'.
the game is: War (card game)
thanks for helpers

```
  btn.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int num = rnd.Next(1, 14);
                int letter = 0;// represent random cards symbol 1-dimond 2-heart  3-spades 4-clubs
                string fileName = "_";
                if (num < 10 && num > 1)
                {
                    fileName = fileName + "0" + num.ToString() + "_of_";
                    if (isBlack)
                    {
                        letter = rnd.Next(1, 3);
                        if (letter == 1)
                        {
                            fileName += "spades";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fileName += "clubs";
                        }
                        //for example: try to create: _5_of_spades
                        btn.BackgroundImage = warCards.Properties.Resources.fileName;
                        btn.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Zoom;
                        btn.Enabled = false;
                        isBlack = !isBlack;

                    }
                }
               };
                this.Controls.Add(btn);
                nextPos.X += 112;

            };
```

Comment: `int letter = 0;` lol ;-)

Comment: Use the [`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames(v=vs.110).aspx) to check the complete names of the resources and use [`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(string name)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the stream of the bitmap, (you can load if from a stream)

Comment: where i should use this command? . the pictures on at thr resource folder are png

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using the `GetObject(string)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection you will be able to retrieve the properties from the Resources type. There aren't many cases you should use reflection if you can solve it using other methods. Just to be complete, this is how you could do it using reflection:

```
        // Get a type reference of the Type containing the auto-generated resources from the .resx
        var resourceType = typeof(Properties.Resources);
        // Retrieve the information about the property containing the image
        var propertyReference = resourceType.GetProperty("_5_of_spades", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        // Retrieve the value of the property
        var propertyValue = propertyReference.GetValue(null) as Image;
```

As mentioned in the comments you can use the Manifest Resources, these contain all files in the project marked with the build action "Embedded Resources" set **instead** of adding it to the Resources.resx file. (properties pane of the selected project item).

Full code example of how to read the embedded resources and store them into a Dictionary.

```
        // A dictionary to hold the images by their names
        var images = new Dictionary<string, Image>();

        // Read the resources of the currently executing assembly
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        // All the names of the files that have a "Build action = Embedded Resource"
        var names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            // Check if it's the resource we want
            if (name.EndsWith(".png", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                // Create a 'sanitized name' which excludes the "{AssemblyName}.Resources." and ".png" part
                var prefix = $"{assembly.GetName().Name}.Resources.".Length;
                var sanitizedName = name.Substring(prefix, name.IndexOf(".png") - prefix);

                // Load the image from the Manifest Resource Stream
                var image = Image.FromStream(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name));

                // Add the image to the dictionary
                images.Add(sanitizedName, image);
            }
        }

        // ...

        // Retrieve the image from the dictionary by it's name
        button1.BackgroundImage = images["_5_of_spades"];

        // ...

        // If at any point forward you wish to unload the images from memory (Besides quiting the application)
        button1.BackgroundImage = null; // Make sure no controls use the image anymore
        Parallel.ForEach(images.Values, (image) => { image.Dispose(); });   // Cleanup in-memory images (Linq and TPL to make it a one-liner)
```